# how to type the return of a function when you need to return an object in which all keys are required or all keys are optional?

Tags: typescript

sorry for my english, can you help please, how to type the return of a function when you need to return an object in which all keys are required or all keys are optional?

example:

```
interface Test {
  x?: number;
  y?: number;
}

const testFunction = (isTrue: boolean): Test => {
  if (isTrue) {
    return { // here we need to return all property of Test
      x: 1,
      y: 1,
    }
  }

  return {
    x: 1
  }
}
```

i know only one variant, but i am not sure, that this is best:

```
type MarkRequired<T extends object, Keys extends keyof T> = Omit<T, Keys> & Required<Pick<T, Keys>>;


const testFunction = (isTrue: boolean): Test => {
  if (isTrue) {
    const data: MarkRequired<Test, keyof Test> = { 
      // clearly advised that all fields must be required, but i don't like it, because need to create variable 
      x: 1,
      y: 1,
    }

    return data
  }

  return {
    x: 1
  }
}
```

maybe someone know more elegant variant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There already exists the utility type `Partial<T>` that makes all properties optional.

You can define your return type, and then say that your function returns either the type, or a Partial of the type.

```js
interface Test {
  x: number;
  y: number;
}

function testFunction(isTrue: boolean): Test | Partial<Test> {
  if (isTrue) {
    return {
      x: 1,
      y: 1,
    }
  }

  return {
    x: 1
  }
}
```

Note though there's little utility to a returned type of `Test | Partial<Test>` as `Test` is always compatible with `Partial<Test>`. I don't think it is possible to narrow the returned type down to just `Test`.

You *could* use overloads so the returned type isn't a union, but you must be aware that overloaded implementations aren't type checked completely.

```js
function testFunctionOverloaded(isTrue: true): Test
function testFunctionOverloaded(isTrue: false): Partial<Test>
function testFunctionOverloaded(isTrue: boolean): Test | Partial<Test> {

  if (isTrue) {
    // Typescript will not give an error if we still return Partial<Test> here
    return {
      x: 1,
      y: 1,
    }
  }

  return {
    x: 1
  }
}

const trueValue = testFunctionOverloaded(true); // returns Test
const falseValue = testFunctionOverloaded(false); // returns Partial<Test>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest taking a look at `MarkRequired` - `MarkRequired<Type, Keys>`. It constructs a type by picking all properties from type Type where properties Keys are set as required.

**Heres an example of how you would do it: [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/AQ4SwOwFwUwJwGYEMDGNgBUYGcoHkAHKMAewiQBtgBvAKFFAA8B%20ALmAgFcBbAI3gDc9BsACebDj35whDAL7CQi8NHjI0mHFABKMAI6cwcGABMaykI3Zc%20gi2OtS785coScIKYmWCxcAMQ8vUggACjBsDDhOGHYoaJgASnYsXF0DI1NZUHdPbwhfLUC8kPDIhPZkCmwklK1CfMpskFzgnz8oYrawiKiY9l4SEgoYJAhkzVwGkMpgAB9JnX1DYzM6EXAEYDK%20pPMNkGMoTjgC9YPLdgBGABp7BlFru4u5ZtAFBnsjk7P74CtgFd7K9lB9QMoUGRcMBjBlVqkoMAALyFAJBfKheIxRICYAAejxNH%20TwcgOAYJAkIg0JIRBmFARyNRnXRpSqNRx%20MJ1GJZIUtFoQA)**

```
interface TestOptional {
  x?: number;
  y?: number;
}

interface TestRequired {
  x: number;
  y: number;
}

function testFunction(isTrue: true): TestRequired;
function testFunction(isTrue: false): TestOptional;
function testFunction(isTrue: boolean): TestOptional | TestRequired {
  if (isTrue) {
    return {
      x: 1,
      y: 1,
    };
  }

  return {
    x: 1
  };
}

const requiredTest = testFunction(true); // { x: 1, y: 1 }
const optionalTest = testFunction(false); // { x: 1 }
```